# grammatically of understand vs understood

Tags: tense, past-perfect

> Although, if you **understand** such terms of grammar, you probably wouldn't have asked the question.

I think, the past tense of ***understand*** should be used, as the next sentence is in future perfect.

> Although, if you **understood**  such terms of grammar, you probably wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: The second one is better, but I would prefer to keep both as perfect tense: "Although, if you *had understood* such terms of grammar, you probably wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Both parse, but you almost always want the second.

In your first sentence, the verb tenses do not agree. That is not *necessarily* wrong, but it almost always is not what you want. As phrased, it means "If you understand (**now**), you wouldn't have asked (**then**)."

Your second sentence is much more likely. As phrased, it means "If you understood (**then**), you wouldn't have asked (**then**)." This makes better sense logically.